# Разбить совпадение на составляющие используя регулярное выражение

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Только недавно начал работать с регулярными выражениями и столкнулся со следующей задачей:

**Исходные данные:** строка, содержащая фразы, экранированные в {}. В {} могут содержаться несколько фраз (2 и более).

**Выходные данные:** исходная строка, содержащая вместо {...} случайную фразу из {...}

**Текущий код**

```py
import re
import random

def shuffle(str):
    ns = ''
    pattern = re.compile(r"{([^}]+)}")
    for elem in pattern.split(str):
        if '|' in elem:
            ns += random.choice(elem.split('|'))
        else:
            ns += elem

    return ns

str = 'Привет. {Меня зовут Сергей.|Как тебя зовут?|Как зовут твою сестру?}'
print (shuffle(str))    # Привет. Как зовут твою сестру?
print (shuffle(str))    # Привет. Как тебя зовут?
print (shuffle(str))    # Привет. Меня зовут Сергей.
```

Собственно сейчас совпадение это все, что находится в {}. После этого совпадение разбивается по символу | и уже только тогда выбирается фраза.

**Вопрос**: можно ли составить такой паттерн, который сразу бы группировал фразы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Можно ли составить такой паттерн, который сразу бы группировал фразы?*
 - **нельзя**, если не известно точное количество групп.

Дело в том, что для этого нам понадобится повторять группы захвата, а сделать это, не зная их точного количества, невозможно (исключение - [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)).

*Похожий англоязычный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463694/11558617*

---

Для того, чтобы понять, зачем нам нужно повторять группы захвата, давайте обсудим, как мог бы выглядеть нужный нам паттерн.

Предположим, что строка выглядит так: `Some text. {spam|eggs|holy hand grenade|hello}!`
Наша группа, выделенная `{}`, окружена каким-то текстом и на выбор в ней 4 варианта.

Для начала мы бы добрались до данных в скобках `{(.*)}`:

```py
print(re.findall(r'{(.*)}', string)[0])
'spam|eggs|holy hand grenade|hello'
```

Далее мы обработали бы крайний случай - конец списка `([^\|]*)`:

```py
print(re.findall(r'{(.*\|)([^\|]*)}', string)[0])
('spam|eggs|holy hand grenade|', 'hello')
```

Осталось разделить `spam|eggs|holy hand grenade|`.
Для этого необходимо повторить паттерн `([^\|]*)\|` несколько раз.

Именно это и невозможно сделать, если не знать точное количество групп.
Попробуем добавить в наше выражение паттерн `(?:([^\|]*)\|)*` и посмотрим, что получится:

```py
print(re.findall(r'{(?:([^\|]*)\|)*([^\|]*)}', string)[0])
('holy hand grenade', 'hello')
```

Вернулось только последнее слово, хотя группа захвата повторялась 3 раза.

Дело в том, что движок перезаписал все предыдущие совпадения и вернул только последнее. 
Подробное описание того, почему так происходит, можете прочитать [здесь](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).
*(Единственным исключением из этого правила является [механизм](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) регулярных выражений .NET, который сохраняет информацию о возврате для захвата групп после попытки сопоставления.)*

Других вариантов (если не разделять строку на части) у нас не остаётся.

---

Если же точное количество групп известно (например, 3), то их можно банально повторить:

```py
print(re.findall(r'.*{([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*)}.*', string)[0])
('spam', 'eggs', 'holy hand grenade', 'hello')
```

Comment: Да, именно с проблемой повторения я и столкнулся. Вот только ваш код не сработает для строки, если в ней будет 2+ группы {}

Comment: @TheMarhang, действительно, упустил это из виду. Пожалуй, вообще уберу, раз у Вас есть реализация.